# Proper way of using NAMESPACE and USE for my custom model in LARAVEL 4.1

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-4, composer-php

My composer.json currently have these:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
}
```

If I have

```
<?php
namespace Models;
use Eloquent;
class User extends Eloquent {
```

I get this error: `Class 'User' not found`

But if I only have:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {
```

I can call instantiate/call User class via `new User()` or `User::*`.

I don't know why. First time using `namespace` and `use` in PHP. I understand the use of `namespace` and `use`, it just, .... Is it the setup? Or there's more configuration? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent namespaces is `'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',`.

You can app/config/app.php  `'aliases' => array()` examine.